# Update field in subform based on field in modal dialog

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a master form (frmServices) with two sub forms (frmExpensesSubForm and frmMileageSubForm). Services and expenses are linked one to many with a serviceID field. frmExpensesSubForm  is a data sheet view containing expenseDate, Amount and a combo box for expenseType. If the expenseType chosen is "Auto Mileage" the frmMileageSubForm displays as a modal dialog with a reimburseRate specific to the expenseDate for the record in the frmExpensesSubForm. On the frmMileageSubForm when a distanceTravelled entry is made, the reimburseAmount is calculated as the product of the rate and the distance. All this is currently working.

How, in VBA, do I update the Amount field in the frmExpensesSubForm to the calculated reimburseAmount when the "OK" button is clicked? I tried:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Forms!frmServices!frmExpensesSubForm.Amount = Forms!frmServices!MileageSubForm.reimburseAmount
End Sub
```

but I get a runtime 438 error.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Forms!frmServices!frmExpensesSubForm!Amount = Forms!frmServices!MileageSubForm!reimburseAmount
```

Note the **!** in front of Amount and reimburseAmount.

In general, either use **!** or **.** in your form expressions, and try not to mix them.